# increase maximum recursion depth tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, tensorflow

Is there a hack so that I can increase the maximum recursion depth allowed? I only need it to be 2-3 times as big.

I have a tensorflow graph with many tensors that are lazily constructed because they depend on other tensors (which may or may not be constructed yet). I can guarantee that this process terminates, and that I will not run out of memory. However, I run into this recursion depth error.

Comment: Is this just a Python error during graph construction? If so, you can [set Python's recursion limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323013/6824418).

Comment: yes I think it was.

Answer (score 0):

I had made a coding error that referenced a tensor in the construction of the same tensor. I don't know if changing recursion depth would solve similar, but unbugged, situations.